# DownloadListener

Tags: android

Добрый день! У меня есть WebView, через который загружаю файлы. В некоторых браузерах я видел, что при нажатии на файл вылетало окно, спрашивающее, через что скачать: Браузер, Какой-то имеющийся загрузчик...
В моём же случае оно просто скачивает файл. В программу я встроил менеджер загрузок, но его система не видит и опять-же тупо скачивает файл. Как быть?

Answer (score 3):

Ваш загрузчик должен "доложиться" системе (через манифест), что умеет качать определенные типы файлов (например JPG как в этом примере):

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Тогда при попытке загрузить определенный URL с жипегом, через Intent

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
```

Будет вытащен на свет божий диалоговый боксик в выбором загрузчика и среди прочих будет ваш активити

Comment: А если загрузчик должен загружать любой тип файлов, как и встроенный? Форматов уйма, не писать же все!

Comment: Дык укажите паттерн в виде звездочки и будет вам щастье

P.S. С Наступающим!